# ComboBox doesn't show current value of assigned field inside a ListView

Tags: wpf, data-binding, listview, combobox, selecteditem

I have a DataTemplate with a Combobox inside a ListView like this

```
<GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Dimensions, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}"
                                DisplayMemberPath="Description"
                                SelectedValuePath="Id"
                                SelectedItem="{Binding DimName}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

The combobox is populated correctly, but it doesn't select the content according to underlying field (ie. Dimension.DimName).

Here's how the ListView is declared

```
<ListView 
  Name="lstCriteria"
  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
  Margin="5"
  AlternationCount="2" 
  ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource CriteriaItemStyle}"
  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CriteriaList}}" DockPanel.Dock="Top"
  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
```

If I replace combobox with a TextBlock it does show the DimName Field's value, like this

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding DimName}"/>
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does your `DimName` come directly from the `Dimensions` list?

By default, if a ComboBox's Items is set to a custom class, it will compare the `SelectedItem` to an item in the `ItemSource` by reference. It will not match the item if they do not refer to the exact same object in memory, even if the object's data is the same.

To get around that you can either set `SelectedValue` and `SelectedValuePath` instead of `SelectedItem` on your ComboBox, or you can overwrite the `Equals()` method of your `DimName` class to return true if an object's data is equal

**Edit**

In regards to your comment below, is `DimName` a `Dimension` object? If so then setting `SelectedItem` should work fine. If it's an long you'll need to set `SelectedValue`, not `SelectedItem`. If it's something else, you may need a converter to convert it into a `Dimension` object

Comment: Hi Rachel, Dimensions list is `List<Dimension>`. Dimension class already is implementing `Equals()` method. And I am already using `SelectedValuePath` to access the Dimension.Id property. Dimension.Id is a Long data type, and hence, if I try to use `SelectedValue`, it is throwing some exception regarding mismatch of the Format. Is there a way around using DataTemplate for Combobox?

Comment: `Equals()` method is using Id field to compare objects.

Comment: @Pak Is `DimName` a `Dimension` object? If so then setting `SelectedItem` should work fine. If it's an `long` you'll need to set `SelectedValue`, not `SelectedItem`. If it's something else, you may need a converter to cast it into a `Dimension` object

Comment: What you said was right and to make my code work, I had to correct it according to your suggestions. I will post it as another answer so that it could be helpful to someone else in future.

Comment: @Pak Updated my answer to include the comment :)

Answer (score 0):

As Rachel suggested, I added a new Property to my class called Dimension of class Dimension like this

```
    public Dimension Dimension
    {
        get { return _dimension; }
        set { _dimension = value; }
    }
```

and then set SelectedItem="{Binding Dimension}" as follows,

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Dimensions, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}"
                                              DisplayMemberPath="Description"
                                              SelectedValuePath="Id"
                                              SelectedItem="{Binding Dimension}">
                                            </ComboBox>
```

The silly mistake I was making was, 
As my combobox was populating correctly, I was hoping that WPF will somehow match the DimName content with one of the items in the ComboBox automatically, which is not possible.